# In python, why does calling a string, "X", display it in ASCII, but calling "print X" display it in unicode?

Tags: python, string, unicode, encoding, ascii

I've got a list of strings, along the lines of `list=[a,b,c,d,e]`.

When I call `list[2]`, the string `c` is displayed as ASCII; when I call `print list[2]`, however, it's displayed as unicode. Why does this discrepancy exist?

Comment: For similar reasons to why `"123"` displays differently than `print "123"`.

Comment: Could you show an *unedited* transcript of the phenomenon, please?  We don't know what you mean by "calling" - neither strings nor `print` statements are "callable" in Python jargon - and we also don't know what you mean by "ascii" and "unicode".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is mainly because strings in Python 2 are not text strings but **byte strings**.

I suppose you are in a REPL environment (a Python console). When you evaluate something in the console, you get its *printed representation* which is the same as calling `print repr()` on the expression:

```
l = ['ñ']
l[0] # should output '\xc3\xb1'
print repr(l[0]) # should output the same
```

This is because your console is in UTF-8 mode (if you get a different representation for `ñ` it is because your console uses some other text representation) so when you press `ñ` you are actually entering two bytes `0xc3` and `0xb1`.

[`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr) is a Python method that always returns a string. For primitive types, this string is a valid source to rebuild the value passed as parameter. This case it returns a string with a sequence of bytes that recreates another string with the `ñ` encoded as UTF-8. To see this:

```
repr(l[0]) # should print a string within a string: "'\\xc3\\xb1'"
```

So when you print it (which is the same as just evaluating in the console), you get the same string without the outer quotes and the escaped characters properly replaced. I.e:

```
print repr(l[0]) # should output '\xc3\xb1'
```

But, when you print the value, i.e: `print l[0]`, then you send those two bytes to the console. As the console is in UTF-8 mode, it decodes the sequence and translate it to only one character: `ñ`. So:

```
print l[0] # should output ñ
```

If you want to store text strings, you must use the modifier `u` before the string. This way:

```
text = u'ñ'
```

Now, when evaluating text you will see [its Unicode codepoint](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/f1/index.htm):

```
text # should output u'\xf1'
```

And printing it should recreate the `ñ` glyph:

```
print text # should output `ñ`
```

If you want to convert `text` into a byte string representation, you need an encoding scheme (such as UTF-8):

```
text.encode('utf-8') == l[0] # should output True
```

Similarly, it you want the Unicode representation for `l[0]`, you'll need to decode those bytes:

```
l[0].decode('utf-8') == text # should output True
```

All this said, notice in Python 3, default strings are indeed Unicode Strings and you need to prefix the literal notation with `b` to produce byte strings.

Answer (score 2):

It's because those two ways of displaying a string use different routes to get to the final result. `x` by itself in the REPL will invoke `repr(x)` and display that, but `print(x)` will invoke `str(x)` and display that instead. Classes are allowed to define `__repr__` and `__str__` separately, so they don't always return the same value.

```
>>> x = u"a"
>>> x
u'a'
>>> print x
a
>>> repr(x)
"u'a'"
>>> str(x)
'a'
>>>
```